# Grub Command to View Output of a Command X amount of lines at a time

Tags: grub2

Is there a GRUB command that acts like the more (or less) command in Linux?

Comment: On a side note, may I ask why you need such functionality in your boot loader?

Comment: One example would be when using the GRUB shell and running the help command. The output is a long list of commands but I can only see the end of it do to the page scrolling. I'd like to be able to parse that list.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Command_002dline-and-menu-entry-commands), not by default. I would imagine that you could add a simple program that does what you desire (if you can find one) into the appropriate grub directory (likely `/boot/grub/yourInstallationType` where yourInstallationType might be x86_64-efi) and tweaking configuration files as needed, but it would likely be more work than what you would like to put in.